# Save JPG in progressive format

Tags: .net, html, image, compression, jpeg

```
<Extension()> _
Public Sub Save(ByVal b As Bitmap, ByVal FileName As String, ByVal Compression As Long, ByVal MimeType As String)
    Dim Params As EncoderParameters = New EncoderParameters(2)
    Dim CodecInfo As ImageCodecInfo = GetEncoderInfo(MimeType)

    Params.Param(0) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.RenderMethod, EncoderValue.RenderProgressive)
    Params.Param(1) = New EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, Compression)

    b.Save(FileName, CodecInfo, Params)
End Sub
```

this does not work. Its not saved as progressive. How can i do this, and maybe also specify the nr of passes.??

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it's not supported. I have tried code suggested [here](http://forums.asp.net/p/949375/2629407.aspx#2629407) and [here](http://p2p.wrox.com/asp-net-1-x-2-0-application-design/43556-progressive-jpg-image.html) and arrived at this C# code:

```
using (Image source = Image.FromFile(@"D:\temp\test2.jpg")) {

  ImageCodecInfo codec = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders().First(c => c.MimeType == "image/jpeg");

  EncoderParameters parameters = new EncoderParameters(3);
  parameters.Param[0] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.Quality, 100L);
  parameters.Param[1] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.ScanMethod, (int)EncoderValue.ScanMethodInterlaced);
  parameters.Param[2] = new EncoderParameter(System.Drawing.Imaging.Encoder.RenderMethod, (int)EncoderValue.RenderProgressive);

  source.Save(@"D:\temp\saved.jpg", codec, parameters);
}
```

Setting both interlaced and progressive mode, it still saves a regular baseline JPEG. I have tried any combination of either setting and their alternative settings (non-interlaced and non-progressive), and haven't seen any difference at all in the resulting image file.

I haven't found any response from anyone saying that they have actually managed to save a progressive JPEG in .NET.

Both the `ScanMethodInterlaced` and `RenderProgressive` parameter values are described only as "Not used in GDI+ version 1.0." in 
[the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.encodervalue.aspx).

Comment: @diamandiev Why is this marked as an answer?  This does not give any answer as to how to save in progressive format - Just that it says that you cannot.  It can be quite misleading for readers.

Comment: @Guffa do newer version of GDI+ supports progressive jpeg. if so, from which version it is supported.

Comment: @ArjunVachhani: I haven't found anything that suggests that it has been added.

Comment: it is not working when creating jpeg from bitmap .Any solution for it ?

Answer (score 4):

I suppose to use [jpegtran](http://jpegclub.org/jpegtran/) utility as described in [Image Optimization, Part 4: Progressive JPEG…Hot or Not?](http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2008/12/05/imageopt-4/) article:

```
jpegtran -copy none -progressive input.jpg output.jpg
```

In addition you can optimize Haffman tables by such way:

```
jpegtran -copy none -optimize input.jpg output.jpg
```