# save a JPEG in progressive format

Tags: c#, asp.net, encoding, jpeg

A similar question has already been asked on this thread:

[Save JPG in progressive format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2267717/save-jpg-in-progressive-format)

However, the answer marked is basically saying that it can't be done.  However, considering it is done using other software, it definitely is something which C# can do.

Is there any way this can be done?

Comment: I'd start by examining some of the C++ code that does this. See http://www.jonolick.com/uploads/7/9/2/1/7921194/jo_jpeg.cpp (code looks like crap, but it works)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Magick.NET](http://magick.codeplex.com/) can do it with a code like this

```
using (MagickImage image = new MagickImage("input.png"))
{
  // Set the format and write to a stream so ImageMagick won't detect the file type.
  image.Format = MagickFormat.Pjpeg;
  using (FileStream fs = new FileStream("output.jpg", FileMode.Create))
  {
    image.Write(fs);
  }
  // Write to .jpg file
  image.Write("PJEG:output.jpg");
  // Or to a .pjpeg file
  image.Write("output.pjpg");
}
```

You can find more details [here](http://magick.codeplex.com/discussions/450804).

Comment: That links to the ImageMagick library, which is not native.

Comment: It's not, but it is clear from the older question that there is currently no native support for this http://stackoverflow.com/a/2268376/537682. In that case I don't see the reason of reasking this question.

Comment: @CharlieKilian By 'natively', I was understanding directly from C# code, not say using an external executable.  I understand this could have been misleading, and I have now updated the title.

Comment: @ZoltánKocsán Thanks! Just tried it and works great !